# Use a script with GNU license

Tags: web-applications, licensing

I have a question about softwares and webapps license.
I get a php script, it published with "GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE".
Can I use this script in my webapp, and when my app is complete (I write my code and design pages), can I sell this app?? (I won't change license of that script, just the license of downloaded script!)
Thanks...

Comment: OOC, what script are we talking about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to determine to what extent your app depends on the GPL script. If your app doesn't work without the script, then I think it's safe to say that it depends on it on a fundamental way. If this is the case, then your code must also be released under the GPL license - please notice that this doesn't imply that you can not sell your app, you are free to do so, but now the code of your app must be available for any one to use, see, modify, and distribute the modifications.

If you're not OK with the last part, maybe you should look for other script alternatives, licensed under a more permisible model. For instance, any of the following licenses would be fine: Apache, MIT, even LGPL

Answer (score 1):

As long as the script doesn't put part of itself into your code when you use it, you should be OK. IOW: If it is just some kind of tool you use to help build your real code (which is totally separate and entirely your own work), then you can liscense that stuff however you want.

What you can't do is relicense somebody else's work without their permission. If the script injects part of itself into your code, that would include that injected part. Also, if you link anything GPLed (object file, link library, etc), then your license needs to be GPL-compatible (and the linked part has to stay GPL).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the GPL is that if your code relies on the script, then you have to release your code under the GPL as well.  If your code interfaces with the script, but it isn't a neccessary component (i.e. the script is or is part of a module or plugin) then only the module/plugin needs to be released under the GPL.  IANAL...